building dataset for multivariate deep ar with gluonts
I'm trying to build a gluon ts deep ar model, but struggling to get the dataset into the correct shape. The input data is a pandas dataframe, which looks like this:

To format the data according to gluonts requirements, I have tried the following:
df_train = df_raw[:1000]
df_valid = df_raw[1000:]

train = PandasDataset(dict(df_train[:]), target="USGG10YR Index")
valid = PandasDataset(dict(df_valid), target="USGG10YR Index")

However, when I run this code:
estimator = DeepAREstimator(freq='D', prediction_length=90, num_layers=3, trainer_kwargs={'accelerator': 'auto', 'max_epochs':30})

predictor = estimator.train(train, num_workers=2)

I get the following error:
{
    "name": "KeyError",
    "message": "'USGG10YR Index'",
    "stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3805, in Index.get_loc(self, key)
   3804 try:
-> 3805     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3806 except KeyError as err:

File index.pyx:167, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File index.pyx:191, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File index.pyx:228, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._get_loc_duplicates()

KeyError: 'USGG10YR Index'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[198], line 3
      1 estimator = DeepAREstimator(freq='D', prediction_length=90, num_layers=3, trainer_kwargs={'accelerator': 'auto', 'max_epochs':30})
----> 3 predictor = estimator.train(train, num_workers=2)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gluonts/torch/model/estimator.py:246, in PyTorchLightningEstimator.train(self, training_data, validation_data, shuffle_buffer_length, cache_data, ckpt_path, **kwargs)
    237 def train(
    238     self,
    239     training_data: Dataset,
   (...)
    244     **kwargs,
    245 ) -> PyTorchPredictor:
--> 246     return self.train_model(
    247         training_data,
    248         validation_data,
    249         shuffle_buffer_length=shuffle_buffer_length,
    250         cache_data=cache_data,
    251         ckpt_path=ckpt_path,
    252     ).predictor

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gluonts/torch/model/estimator.py:209, in PyTorchLightningEstimator.train_model(self, training_data, validation_data, from_predictor, shuffle_buffer_length, cache_data, ckpt_path, **kwargs)
    200 custom_callbacks = self.trainer_kwargs.pop(\"callbacks\", [])
    201 trainer = pl.Trainer(
    202     **{
    203         \"accelerator\": \"auto\",
   (...)
    206     }
    207 )
--> 209 trainer.fit(
    210     model=training_network,
    211     train_dataloaders=training_data_loader,
    212     val_dataloaders=validation_data_loader,
    213     ckpt_path=ckpt_path,
    214 )
    216 if checkpoint.best_model_path != \"\":
    217     logger.info(
    218         f\"Loading best model from {checkpoint.best_model_path}\"
    219     )

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/trainer/trainer.py:544, in Trainer.fit(self, model, train_dataloaders, val_dataloaders, datamodule, ckpt_path)
    542 self.state.status = TrainerStatus.RUNNING
    543 self.training = True
--> 544 call._call_and_handle_interrupt(
    545     self, self._fit_impl, model, train_dataloaders, val_dataloaders, datamodule, ckpt_path
    546 )

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/trainer/call.py:44, in _call_and_handle_interrupt(trainer, trainer_fn, *args, **kwargs)
     42     if trainer.strategy.launcher is not None:
     43         return trainer.strategy.launcher.launch(trainer_fn, *args, trainer=trainer, **kwargs)
---> 44     return trainer_fn(*args, **kwargs)
     46 except _TunerExitException:
     47     _call_teardown_hook(trainer)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/trainer/trainer.py:580, in Trainer._fit_impl(self, model, train_dataloaders, val_dataloaders, datamodule, ckpt_path)
    573 assert self.state.fn is not None
    574 ckpt_path = self._checkpoint_connector._select_ckpt_path(
    575     self.state.fn,
    576     ckpt_path,
    577     model_provided=True,
    578     model_connected=self.lightning_module is not None,
    579 )
--> 580 self._run(model, ckpt_path=ckpt_path)
    582 assert self.state.stopped
    583 self.training = False

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/trainer/trainer.py:989, in Trainer._run(self, model, ckpt_path)
    984 self._signal_connector.register_signal_handlers()
    986 # ----------------------------
    987 # RUN THE TRAINER
    988 # ----------------------------
--> 989 results = self._run_stage()
    991 # ----------------------------
    992 # POST-Training CLEAN UP
    993 # ----------------------------
    994 log.debug(f\"{self.__class__.__name__}: trainer tearing down\")

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/trainer/trainer.py:1035, in Trainer._run_stage(self)
   1033         self._run_sanity_check()
   1034     with torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(self._detect_anomaly):
-> 1035         self.fit_loop.run()
   1036     return None
   1037 raise RuntimeError(f\"Unexpected state {self.state}\")

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/loops/fit_loop.py:194, in _FitLoop.run(self)
    193 def run(self) -> None:
--> 194     self.setup_data()
    195     if self.skip:
    196         return

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/loops/fit_loop.py:258, in _FitLoop.setup_data(self)
    256 self._data_fetcher = _select_data_fetcher(trainer, RunningStage.TRAINING)
    257 self._data_fetcher.setup(combined_loader)
--> 258 iter(self._data_fetcher)  # creates the iterator inside the fetcher
    259 max_batches = sized_len(combined_loader)
    260 self.max_batches = max_batches if max_batches is not None else float(\"inf\")

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/loops/fetchers.py:106, in _PrefetchDataFetcher.__iter__(self)
    104 for _ in range(self.prefetch_batches):
    105     try:
--> 106         batch = super().__next__()
    107         self.batches.append(batch)
    108     except StopIteration:
    109         # this would only happen when prefetch_batches > the number of batches available and makes
    110         # `__next__` jump directly to the empty iterator case without trying to fetch again

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/loops/fetchers.py:56, in _DataFetcher.__next__(self)
     54 self._start_profiler()
     55 try:
---> 56     batch = next(self.iterator)
     57 except StopIteration:
     58     self.done = True

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/utilities/combined_loader.py:326, in CombinedLoader.__next__(self)
    324 def __next__(self) -> _ITERATOR_RETURN:
    325     assert self._iterator is not None
--> 326     out = next(self._iterator)
    327     if isinstance(self._iterator, _Sequential):
    328         return out

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/utilities/combined_loader.py:74, in _MaxSizeCycle.__next__(self)
     72 for i in range(n):
     73     try:
---> 74         out[i] = next(self.iterators[i])
     75     except StopIteration:
     76         self._consumed[i] = True

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gluonts/itertools.py:420, in IterableSlice.__iter__(self)
    419 def __iter__(self):
--> 420     yield from itertools.islice(self.iterable, self.length)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gluonts/transform/_base.py:111, in TransformedDataset.__iter__(self)
    110 def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[DataEntry]:
--> 111     yield from self.transformation(
    112         self.base_dataset, is_train=self.is_train
    113     )

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gluonts/transform/_base.py:132, in MapTransformation.__call__(self, data_it, is_train)
    129 def __call__(
    130     self, data_it: Iterable[DataEntry], is_train: bool
    131 ) -> Iterator:
--> 132     for data_entry in data_it:
    133         try:
    134             yield self.map_transform(data_entry.copy(), is_train)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gluonts/dataset/loader.py:55, in Stack.__call__(self, data, is_train)
     54 def __call__(self, data, is_train):
---> 55     for batch in data:
     56         yield rows_to_columns(batch, np.array)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gluonts/dataset/loader.py:50, in Batch.__call__(self, data, is_train)
     49 def __call__(self, data, is_train):
---> 50     yield from batcher(data, self.batch_size)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gluonts/itertools.py:128, in batcher.<locals>.get_batch()
    127 def get_batch():
--> 128     return list(itertools.islice(it, batch_size))

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gluonts/transform/_base.py:132, in MapTransformation.__call__(self, data_it, is_train)
    129 def __call__(
    130     self, data_it: Iterable[DataEntry], is_train: bool
    131 ) -> Iterator:
--> 132     for data_entry in data_it:
    133         try:
    134             yield self.map_transform(data_entry.copy(), is_train)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gluonts/transform/_base.py:111, in TransformedDataset.__iter__(self)
    110 def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[DataEntry]:
--> 111     yield from self.transformation(
    112         self.base_dataset, is_train=self.is_train
    113     )

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gluonts/transform/_base.py:186, in FlatMapTransformation.__call__(self, data_it, is_train)
    182 def __call__(
    183     self, data_it: Iterable[DataEntry], is_train: bool
    184 ) -> Iterator:
    185     num_idle_transforms = 0
--> 186     for data_entry in data_it:
    187         num_idle_transforms += 1
    188         for result in self.flatmap_transform(data_entry.copy(), is_train):

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gluonts/itertools.py:85, in Cyclic.__iter__(self)
     83 at_least_one = False
     84 while True:
---> 85     for el in self.iterable:
     86         at_least_one = True
     87         yield el

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gluonts/transform/_base.py:111, in TransformedDataset.__iter__(self)
    110 def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[DataEntry]:
--> 111     yield from self.transformation(
    112         self.base_dataset, is_train=self.is_train
    113     )

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gluonts/transform/_base.py:132, in MapTransformation.__call__(self, data_it, is_train)
    129 def __call__(
    130     self, data_it: Iterable[DataEntry], is_train: bool
    131 ) -> Iterator:
--> 132     for data_entry in data_it:
    133         try:
    134             yield self.map_transform(data_entry.copy(), is_train)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gluonts/transform/_base.py:132, in MapTransformation.__call__(self, data_it, is_train)
    129 def __call__(
    130     self, data_it: Iterable[DataEntry], is_train: bool
    131 ) -> Iterator:
--> 132     for data_entry in data_it:
    133         try:
    134             yield self.map_transform(data_entry.copy(), is_train)

    [... skipping similar frames: MapTransformation.__call__ at line 132 (8 times)]

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gluonts/transform/_base.py:132, in MapTransformation.__call__(self, data_it, is_train)
    129 def __call__(
    130     self, data_it: Iterable[DataEntry], is_train: bool
    131 ) -> Iterator:
--> 132     for data_entry in data_it:
    133         try:
    134             yield self.map_transform(data_entry.copy(), is_train)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gluonts/dataset/pandas.py:217, in PandasDataset.__iter__(self)
    216 def __iter__(self):
--> 217     yield from self._data_entries
    218     self.unchecked = True

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gluonts/dataset/pandas.py:191, in PandasDataset._pair_to_dataentry(self, item_id, df)
    180     assert is_uniform(df.index), (
    181         \"Dataframe index is not uniformly spaced. \"
    182         \"If your dataframe contains data from multiple series in the \"
    183         'same column (\"long\" format), consider constructing the '
    184         \"dataset with `PandasDataset.from_long_dataframe` instead.\"
    185     )
    187 entry = {
    188     \"start\": df.index[0],
    189 }
--> 191 target = df[self.target].values
    192 target = target[: len(target) - self.future_length]
    193 entry[\"target\"] = target.T

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:4102, in DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
   4100 if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   4101     return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 4102 indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   4103 if is_integer(indexer):
   4104     indexer = [indexer]

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3812, in Index.get_loc(self, key)
   3807     if isinstance(casted_key, slice) or (
   3808         isinstance(casted_key, abc.Iterable)
   3809         and any(isinstance(x, slice) for x in casted_key)
   3810     ):
   3811         raise InvalidIndexError(key)
-> 3812     raise KeyError(key) from err
   3813 except TypeError:
   3814     # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
   3815     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3816     #  the TypeError.
   3817     self._check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: 'USGG10YR Index'"
}


It does not appear to recognize the target, but why?
One issue could be that the dates are not evenly spaced, so I tried this:
df_date_range = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start, end))
df_date_range.columns = ['Date']
df0 = pd.merge(bb_raw, df_date_range, on='Date', how='outer')
df1 = pd.merge(c0a4_raw, df_date_range, on='Date', how='outer')
df_raw = pd.merge(df0, df1, on='Date', how='outer').set_index('Date')

Any pointer would be much appreciated.

It appears USGG10YR Index is not a valid column. Please try:
df_train.columns and see if it exists.

I have created a dummy code with the same inputs as you, but can't replicate your issue. I think the issue is in the dataset. Are you sure that you have column "USGG10YR Index" in the dataset?
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from gluonts.dataset.pandas import PandasDataset
from gluonts.dataset.split import split
from gluonts.torch import DeepAREstimator


df_raw = pd.DataFrame(data = {
        "USGG10YR Index": np.arange(2000),
                     "x": np.arange(2000)},
                    index = pd.date_range("2020-01-01", 
                                          periods = 2000, 
                                          freq = '1d'))

df_train = df_raw[:1000]
df_valid = df_raw[1000:]

train = PandasDataset(dict(df_train[:]), target="USGG10YR Index")
valid = PandasDataset(dict(df_valid), target="USGG10YR Index")

estimator = DeepAREstimator(freq='D', 
                            prediction_length=90, 
                            num_layers=3, 
                            trainer_kwargs={'accelerator': 'cpu',
                                             'max_epochs':2})
predictor = estimator.train(train, num_workers=2) # sucessfully trains the model.

